# Deleting item is throwing following exception. What can be possible reasons for this?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Whenever we deleting any item in Sitecore, it gives following error.

> Invalid or unsupported character in number: _
>
> Description: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid or unsupported character in number: _

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentException: Invalid or unsupported character in number: _]
Lucene.Net.Support.Number.ToInt64(String s) +346
Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentInfos.GetCurrentSegmentGeneration(String[] files) +126
Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentInfos.GetCurrentSegmentGeneration(Directory directory) +33
Sitecore.Search.Index.CreateDirectory(String folder) +197
Sitecore.Search.Index..ctor(String name, String folder) +193

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +342
Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters) +119
Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +103
Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +131
Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +961
Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +552
Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +275
Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +579
Sitecore.Search.SearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration() +43
Sitecore.Data.Managers.IndexingManager.UpdateIndexAsync(Database database) +58
Sitecore.MainUtil.RaiseEvent(EventHandler`1 subscribers, Object sender, T eventArgs) +26
Sitecore.Data.Engines.HistoryEngine.AddEntry(HistoryCategory category, HistoryAction action, Item item, ID oldParentId, String additionalInfo) +256
Sitecore.Data.Managers.HistoryProvider.RegisterItemDeleted(Item item, ID oldParentId) +117
Sitecore.Data.Managers.HistoryManager.DataEngine_DeletedItem(Object sender, ExecutedEventArgs`1 e) +83
System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) +0
Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent(EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator) +129
Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SqlArchive.DoArchiveItems(IEnumerable`1 items, ID archivalId) +1093
Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute(Func`1 action, Action recover) +289
Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SqlArchive.ArchiveItem(Item item) +572
Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DeleteItems.Delete(List`1 items) +264
Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DeleteItems.Execute(ClientPipelineArgs args) +101
```

Comment: corrupted index? try full rebuild and delete after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the index is broken.
I have seen similar exceptions working with Lucene when several threads are trying to write something to index.
In most cases removing the folder with the index with further reindex helped.

Comment: saved my day. I deleted the folder and re-run it works. <param desc="folder">foldername</param>

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Stacktrace, it appears this is getting generated by the Reflection system trying to instantiate a type coming from the SearchManager configuration.

There might be a rogue underscore in that part of the config.

Look at /stiecore/admin/showconfig.aspx and do a search for "searchmanager" and inspect the type attribute for an underscore character.